# USB hub advertised as 2.0 actually works as 1.1

Tags: windows, usb, windows-vista, usb-2, usb-hub

I bought this USB hub http://www.ebay.com/itm/281298880612 which is supposed to be a USB 2.0 hub.
When I plug a pendrive in to the hub, Windows gives the message "*This device can perform faster if you connect it to a USB 2.0 port*".
Also, when I transfer a big file to the pendrive, I get transfer speeds of about 900 KB/s, which is way slower than the 5 MB/s I get when I plug the pendrive directly to my laptop.

Also, my external monitor has a built-in 2.0 hub and that one works perfectly at full USB 2.0 speeds.

So, my question... Is it possible that Windows (Vista) incorrectly detects a USB 2.0 hub as being 1.1 ?
If so, how can this be solved?

Comment: It probably wont help in this case, but in the "device manager" visually find the item plugged in, or the hub, highlight it with a click. then in the "View" menu select "Devices by Connection". Now you can follow the path of connections, to see how things are looking to the computer.  . . You could also select to show hidden devices and do some cleanup (uninstal) of old unused and pluged in everywhere ghosted items , to see if less mess there would help the system.  Hubs get stock os drivers usually, it is low possible that chipset drivers or some updates were not done? Test more than 1 item.

Comment: There have been reports (long ago) that USB items that failed to negotiate properly at the higher speeds, and downgraded to the lower speeds. The "compatability" information would get stored in the registry, and retained so when the item was pluged in again, it would still be in the lower mode. Uninstalling all instances of it (ghosted and live) , then rebooting to get it to re-install. Or finding the location in the registry and taking it out that way.

Comment: $1.52 including shipping from China and you're surprised it doesn't work as advertised?

Comment: @fixer1234, I am, because sellers with good reputation like that one usually sell products that really do what they say. I've bought cheap electronics from china dozens of times. And if it doesn't work as described, they refund your money, as they already did in my case.

Comment: You made out OK then.  You got a free USB 1.1 hub. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the supplier handled the problem as a defect, so there is no problem to solve.  Any other reason for the problem would be speculation.